# Get list of all fixtures/assets in javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a pretty common design pattern where I have a package that might have a fixture. Example:

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  // ...
  api.addAssets('fixture.json', 'server');
});
```

Now I am trying to make a package which consumes these packages and feeds in all of their fixtures (on the server).

I am wondering: is there a way to get all server side assets that have been added by a package? Eg, something like

```
Assets.getAll().forEach(function (asset) {
})
```